# Remote debugging using Windbg

Tags: windbg

I m trying to use Windbg to remotely debug a user mode application. I ran Windbg as a server using

```
Windbg -server npipe:pipe=PipeName,IcfEnable
```

and trying to connect to server using windbg running as a client using 
Windbg->Connect to remote session. But it failed to connect to server showing me an error "Access denied".

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Debugging server is Win 8 and client is Windows 2k8.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you are following the steps given [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605113813/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2009/02/09/remote-debugging-connecting-to-a-remote-stub-using-the-microsoft-debugging-tools-for-windows.aspx).

2)This can also happen if both the debuggers in the session aren’t running the same debugger version.

3)Try disabling the firewall in the client machine and try to connect again.